# Does CPython guarantee that dict.keys has the same order as dict.values?

Tags: python, cpython

Does CPython guarantee that `dict.keys()` has the same order as `dict.values()` on an unmodified dict?

In other words, is it always true that:

```
list(d.items()) == list(zip(d.keys(), d.values()))
```

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) say:

> Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order
>   [...] If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond.

However, the CPython source code suggests otherwise. The [implementation of dict.items() in dictobject.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7ba47bbfe38d/Objects/dictobject.c#l1297):

```
/* Preallocate the list of tuples, to avoid allocations during
 * the loop over the items, which could trigger GC, which
 * could resize the dict. :-(
 */
```

So, is it true that `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` on an unmodified dict will always return items in the same order? Even if the GC runs?

If it is true, does this apply just CPython, or just Python 2?

Comment: Why do you think those two quotes conflict? They both say the same thing - the order remains the same *if the dictionary isn't modified*.

Comment: Suppose we told you yes; what do you propose to do with the information? The only use I can think of is to write code that should use `dict.items()`, but avoids doing so for no good reason. :/

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The implication is *if you, the user, do not modify the dict*, but the comment suggests that there are situations where Python itself will modify the dict which would then break the guarentee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is still true, because `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` *do not need to allocate new objects*. You are given a list object with references to the existing key or value objects, respectively, instead.

On the other hand, `dict.items()` needs to create tuple objects to hold your key-value pairs. Hence that comment.

Note that running the GC *itself* does not resize a dictionary; dicitonaries are only ever resized when they run out of space for *new* keys. But triggering a GC can trigger a `__del__` handler, which could add to the dictionary, which could resize.. So it is the *possibility* that other Python code is triggered that could alter the dictionary that is prevented here.

Comment: What about if I trigger object allocation? `x = [d.keys()]` -- at this point, can I still safely call `d.values()` and expect the same ordering?

Comment: @WilfredHughes: but GC *by itself* won't trigger a resize of the dictionary (as item deletions never resize a dictionary, *anyway*); it is the combo of producing tuples *during the traverse* that can cause this, IIRC. I'm trying to find you a reference.

Comment: @WilfredHughes: updated. Sure `x = [d.keys()]` could also trigger a `__del__` method that alters your dictionary. But then you don't have to keep re-building a list of tuples from scratch again.